# Press and hold button does not fire onClick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem with the button in my HTML5 application.

When I press the button a Video player runs and plays the video that is stored locally. My issue now is that when I hold the button and release it, it doesn't fire the video player. I'm using an onclick event on my button.

I want to achieve that if I press and hold the button and then release it, it fires the same event as the one I use with the onclick.

Comment: onmouseup (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseup.asp) should help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onmouseup` event.

```
var button = //your button

button.onmouseup = function() {
//your logic

}
```

Comment: I have tried this and got the following code: 
<button id="Btn2">
 </button>
<script>
var button = document.getElementById("Btn2");

button.onmouseup = function() { //my code here 

};
</script>
but it still only fires the event when I click the button, whe I hold and release it, it doesnt' play it.

Comment: could you post your html?

Comment: I posted it here because the code is too long to post as a comment: The page in which the button appears is a view http://jsfiddle.net/qzmnm54n/1

Answer (score 0):

Actually onmousedown event ***instead*** of onClick will do the trick.

Again the same syntax:

### Javascript

```
<button onmousedown ="clickFunction()">Click me!</button>

function clickFunction(){
//code goes here
}
```

### jQuery

```
function clickFunction(){
   $(button).onmousedown(function(){
       //code goes here
   });
};
```

Comment: mouseUp would be preferable in this case, as mouseDown does not allow the user to change his mind mid-click by dragging the cursor off the element before releasing.

Comment: But I thought that was the actual point. Regardless the time the user clicks, the event must start.

Comment: @Leonidas that's true, it doesn't matter if the user holds the button for 2 seconds or 60 seconds, after the user releases the button, the event must start

Comment: So both answers do what we wanted. If you may pick the one you think is more suitable and straightforward and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

you should use a boolean to save the current state.

```
var mouse_is_down = false;
var current_i = 0;              // current_i is used to handle double click (to not act like a hold)

var button = document.querySelector("#myButton");

button.onmousedown = function(){
    mouse_is_down = true;

    // Do thing here for a mousedown event

    setTimeout(
        (function(index){
            return function(){
                if(mouse_is_down && current_i === index){
                    //do thing when hold                        
                }
            };
        })(++current_i), 500); // time you want to hold before fire action in milliseconds
};

button.onmouseup = function(){
    mouse_is_down = false;
    current_i++;

    // Do thing here for a mouseup event
};
```

Fiddle : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/0bs3omjj/1/)