# Press and hold button and change query selector

Tags: javascript, button, selector, state

based on the question [press and hold button javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635079/press-and-hold-button-javascript) and the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0bs3omjj/1/ i want to change the code to another scenario. I want to check if button1 is onmousedown - hold - onmouseup and if so... the query selector should change to the next button

I tried this

```
<div id="myDIV">
<button class="myButton">button 1</button>
<button class="myButton">button 2</button>
<button class="myButton">button 3</button>
<button class="myButton">button 4</button>
</div>
```

And JavaScript

```
var mouse_is_down = false;
var current_i = 0;    
var buttoncounter = 1;
var button = "";
var buttoncount = 0;

function changebutton() {
 var x = document.getElementById("myDIV").querySelectorAll(".myButton");
 x[buttoncount].style.backgroundColor = "red";
 button = x[buttoncount];
 buttoncount++;
}

changebutton();

button.onmousedown = function(){
 mouse_is_down = true;
 console.log("mousedown" + buttoncounter);

setTimeout(
    (function(index){
        return function(){
            if(mouse_is_down && current_i === index){
                //do thing when hold
                console.log("hold" + buttoncounter);
                console.log(button);

            }
        };
    })(++current_i), 500); // time you want to hold before fire action
};

button.onmouseup = function(){
 mouse_is_down = false;
 current_i++;

 console.log("onmouseup" + buttoncounter);

 console.log("change selector");
 buttoncounter++;
 changebutton();
 console.log(button); 

};
```

But the query selector responds only on the first button (click & hold) - but the javascript changes the color values from the other buttons. What is wrong?

Comment: IDs must be unique.

Comment: *I want to check if button1 is onmousedown - hold - onmouseup and if so... the query selector should change to the next button* Eh? No idea what you’re talking about.

Comment: Voting to close as typo/transient. Shout it from the rooftops: **IDs must be unique.**

Comment: Browsers should just stop rendering a site if it contains duplicate id's, itz the only wayz they'll learnz.

Comment: The id is changed in the first function changebutton() - all buttons with the same id´s are counted... the x variable is counted up if the function is called - however, it works so far, because the color of the button is changed... but i can only press the first button...

Comment: try to use this jquery plugin  http://rawgit.com/pisi/Longclick/master/jquery.longclick-min.js

Comment: @RonnyDee There can't be a case of "all buttons with the same id's are counted". Having multiple elements with the same ID can cause all sorts of bugs, handling the case is implementation/browser specific. Use classes to group similar elements together for easy selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use the same ID multiple times.

Second, you're on the right path, but simply put the `onmouseup` and other calls within your `changebutton()` function:

**Your HTML:**

```
<div id="myDIV">
  <button class="myButton">button 1</button>
  <button class="myButton">button 2</button>
  <button class="myButton">button 3</button>
  <button class="myButton">button 4</button>
</div>
```

**Your Javascript:**

```
var mouse_is_down = false;
var current_i = 0;    
var buttoncounter = 1;
var button = "";
var buttoncount = 0;

function changebutton() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV").querySelectorAll(".myButton");
  x[buttoncount].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  button = x[buttoncount];
  button.onmousedown = function(){
  mouse_is_down = true;

  setTimeout(
    (function(index){
      return function(){
        if(mouse_is_down && current_i === index){
          //do thing when hold
          console.log("hold" + buttoncounter);
          console.log(button);

        }
      };
    })(++current_i), 500); // time you want to hold before fire action
  };

  button.onmouseup = function(){
    mouse_is_down = false;
    current_i++;
    buttoncounter++;
    changebutton();
  };
  buttoncount++;
}

changebutton();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help - i really listen to all comments - but if you are learning javascript step for step, it´s a little difficult and frustrating to solve some (easy) problems.

Comment: That's cool. Next time, try to adjust your question if you get response from SO. The SO community is really helpful but also really clear if you're making mistakes. I'll edit your question now so you understand what is meant.